# What is the multidegree of a curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-schemes, moduli-space

What is the multidegree of a curve $C \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$?

I'm reading [Notes on stable maps and quantum cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9608011) by W. Fulton and R. Pandharipande, and on page 14, there is the sentence

> Let $H$ be the Hilbert scheme of genus $g$ curves in $\mathbb{P}(W) \times \mathbb{P}^r$ of multidegree $(e,d)$.

I know what the Hilbert scheme is, but afaik one needs to specify a Hilbert polynomial $P$. Fixing the (arithmetic) genus defines the constant term, because $g = (-1)^d(P(0) - 1)$, where $d$ is the dimension. The degree of $P$ is given by saying that we consider curves, i.e. $\deg(P) = 1$. So the leading coefficient is still missing.

Of course to define the Hilbet scheme (or even the Hilbert polynomial $P$) we also need to specify a very ample sheaf, or a closed embedding $\mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^N$ for some $N > 0$. I actually have two guesses here, but I don't know which is it:

1. simply take the Segre embedding. Here I have no clue what the multidegree could mean.
2. take the embedding defined by the very ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(e) \boxtimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^m}(d)$, and maybe fix $1$ as the leading coefficient for $P$?

Comment: Let $H\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a general hyperplane, then $e=C\cdot H\times \mathbb{P}^m$. Reversing the roles of $n,m$ you get $d$.

Comment: What is $C \cdot H \times \mathbb{P}^m$? The number of intersections? And do you have any clue how to fix the Hilbert polynomial of such a curve, depending on $(e, d)$?

Comment: Hilbert polynomial will depend on the ample class.

Comment: Yeah, but what is an obvious ample class? You suggest $H \times \mathbb{P}^m$ as a divisor?

Comment: $H\times\mathbb{P}^m$ is not ample.